# MacOS не воспринимает обратный слеш при автозагрузке файлов через composer

Tags: php, composer

Как заменить его на обычный слеш при автозагрузке любого файла?
Я понимаю что нужно написать функцию стр_реплейс, но вот куда её вставить в файлах композера не понимаю

Comment: Обратный слеш где именно?

Comment: В пути подключаемого файла.

Comment: Например: \applications\xampp\xamppfiles\htdocs\php/something\App.php. Композер подключает таким образом, и вот слеш перед файлом нужно заменить на прямой

Comment: Может какой-то пример приведете? Потому что я на MacOS больше 5-ти лет работаю и с такой проблемами вообще не сталкивался ни разу.

Comment: А в `composer.json` в `autoload` что указано?

Comment: {
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ishop\\": "vendor/ishop",
            "app\\": "app"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}

Comment: Там по идее слеш в конце должен быть в `"vendor/ishop/"` и `"app/"`

Comment: Добавил как вы сказали, и с перезагрузкой autoload всё заработало. После чего попробовал убрать слеши в конце, опять перезагрузить и каким-то странным образом оно не перестало работать, хотя до этого перезагружал и это ничего не меняло. В общем ничего не понял, но хорошо что всё решилось. Слеши в коцне, по вашему совету всё же оставил. Спасибо за помощь!